# My iphone 14pro’s hotspot is being used from “other devices” when i have already changed the password multiple times

Tags: iphone, ios, network

My iPhone's (17.1.2) hotspot is being used and I have changed the password multiple times and the “other device” is using like 60mb in 30seconds.

For most of the other people who have had this problem, the cause is usually because their laptop is connected to their iPhone's hotspot or something, but I don't have a laptop so I really don't know how to fix this. Any idea on how to find out? Thanks

Comment: If you don’t use it why not toggle “Allow others to join” off?

Comment: nope i use the hotspot sometimes when im bringing my ipad out

Comment: If they don't have the password, the only way they can activate the hotspot is if the phone and the device connecting are both logged into the same AppleID, and can see each other over BT.

Comment: Hm okay thanks ill go check the devices connected to my apple id

Answer (score 1):

Your hotspot password is not needed if the other device shares your iCloud credentials.

You may have to look up each device: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage/section/devices

Then you'll have to determine if the hotspot is connected over USB or over Bluetooth or over WiFi as all three are enabled when you turn on the hotspot.

Changing the password will only stop non-AppleID validated devices that connect over WiFi.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203302 - This article shows how to reset saved Bluetooth / WiFi connections and you can disconnect the Bluetooth devices (or turn off Bluetooth entirely) on your iPhone to ensure that's not how the internet data is being consumed.